# Migradoc - aligning a table vertically

Tags: migradoc

I would like to position my table by controlling its placement both vertically and horizontally.

I can place it horizontally using the following:

```
Commodtable.Rows.LeftIndent = "5cm"
```

How do I do the same but vertically?  I know there is `verticalalignment` but there are only 3 options: Top, Middle and bottom.

This is so i can eventually place 6 tables in a 3 x 2 arrangement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 3 x 2 arrangement you can add tables to a table.

See this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36304148/162529

Do draw a table at an absolute position you can add the table to a `TextFrame` object.
But to get the 3 x 2 arrangement, I would probably prefer nested tables.